# I Have an array of dictionaries and I want to use them in django. How do I do that?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a array of dictionaries like:

```
[{'name': 'X','class':'A'},{'name':'Y','class':'B'}]
```

I Want the Html to show:

```
Name:X, Class:A
Name:Y, Class:B
```

I'm working on Django project
Please Help

I Have tried to pass the array and separate out the two dictionaries but I'm not able to access the keys inside the dictionaries

**Python**

```
params=my_base2.fetch_allreq(email)
data=[]
for i in params:
    dic={'name': i[0],
         'email': i[1],
         'item': i[2],
         'room': i[3]}
    data.append(dic)
print(data)
content={
 'Requests':data
}
return render(request,'dashboard.html',content )
```

**HTML**

```
  {% for lists in Requests %}
   {{lists}}

  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `render` method, you need to pass `content` as the `context` named variable:

```
return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context=content)
```

Then your code should work.